# Apply CIGaussianBlur effect on transparent image

Tags: swift, uiimage, core-image

I'm trying to apply CIGaussianBlur effect on transparent image. The problem is that after applying this effect on my image it loses transparency and becomes black.

Code that I'm using:

```
func blurImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
  let context = CIContext(options: nil)
  let inputImage = CIImage(image: image)
  let originalOrientation = image.imageOrientation
  let originalScale = image.scale

  let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
  filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
  filter?.setValue(5.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
  let outputImage = filter?.outputImage

  var cgImage:CGImage?

  if let outputImage = outputImage <--HERE it's already black!
  {
    cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: (inputImage?.extent)!)
  }

  if let cgImageA = cgImage
  {
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImageA, scale: originalScale, orientation: originalOrientation)
  }

  return nil
}
```

edit: keep in mind that `inputAVector` key is not working with CIGaussianBlur.

Comment: Just as a wild and crazy experiment, try saying `let outputImage = filter?.outputImage.clampedToExtent()`.

Comment: @matt Sadly, no luck. Maybe it's not even possible to apply blur effects on transparent images? Although I saw some apps doing that.

Comment: Very strange... I tested the `CIGaussianBlur` with transparent images on different devices, and it works just as expected. Have you tried loading the image differently into Core Image (not via `UIImage`)? Can you maybe share the image you are trying to blur? Thanks!

Comment: @SwiftyLifestyle - using your code as-is, with this image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnL7P.png ... I get this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHoej.png   -- image views have `.clear` background color, top is original, bottom is the return from `blurImage()`

Comment: Alright I found out that the problem was not with the blur effect.. Sorry for wasting your time! (the problem was that I was passing wrong opaque parameter into UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions..)